# Image tags returned by KCfinder are incomplete on CKeditor

Tags: html, ckeditor, image, inline-editing

Image tags returned by KCfinder are incomplete on CKeditor and not displayed/saved correctly. Note that i am using an inline CKEditor and KCFinder for image upload.

Here are the integration codes:

ckeditor/config.js

```
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = base_url+'/js/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = base_url+'/js/kcfinder/browse.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = base_url+'/js/kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = base_url+'/js/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = base_url+'/js/kcfinder/upload.php?type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = base_url+'/js/kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash';
```

On page HTML

```
<div id="page_body" contenteditable="true" class="full">...</div>
```

On page JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;           
            var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( 'page_body', {
                on: {
                    focus: function(event){
                        var data = event.editor.getData();
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    blur: function( event ) {
                        var data = event.editor.getData();
                        var page_id = <?php echo $this->uri->segment(3) ?>;
                        var page_link =$("#page_link").val();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/dashboard/ajaxChangePageData') ?>',
                            data: { page_id: page_id, page_body: data,page_link:page_link },
                            beforeSend:function(){},
                            success:function(data){},
                            error:function(){ alert("Error"); }
                        });      

                    }
                }
            } );

        </script>
```

Strange is that i can browse the server/upload without any error with KCFinder i can even select an image from the server and the image is shown successfully in the content. but the code width height info are not present after a reload. I figured that the html created for the image was incomplete

in source mode i see-

```
<img alt="" src="/gchalk/content/images/333(1).jpg"  300px; height: 224px;" />
```

The situation just gets worse if for the second time i make some changes to the div say add some text. The image is lost and its treated as text, the above piece of code is shown as

in source mode-

```
&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; data-cke-saved-src=&quot;/gchalk/content/images/333(1).jpg&quot; src=&quot;/gchalk/content/images/333(1).jpg&quot; 300px;=&quot;&quot; height:=&quot;&quot; 224px;&quot;=&quot;&quot;&gt;
```

and it appears on browser/editor as -

```
<img alt="" data-cke-saved-src="/gchalk/content/images/333(1).jpg" src="/gchalk/content/images/333(1).jpg" 300px;="" height:="" 224px;"="">
```

I am tearing my hair for a day and cant find a way around. Please help me out to figure how to solve it.

Oh, and for the record the text is saved in MySQL as "TEXT" through the ajax post i am pretty sure its not a problem but still just saying!

I notice the image tag gets messed up in the default ckeditor(not inline) too.

Comment: I think its GIGO, garbej in garbej out,

the source <img alt="" src="/gchalk/content/images/333(1).jpg"  300px; height: 224px;" /> is wrong

it should be <img alt="" src="/gchalk/content/images/333(1).jpg"  width="300px" height="224px" />

Script functions are not smart functions they will assume input and modify accordingly.. try the new input output will be fine :)

Comment: The problm is i dont suppose my user to write html code, they will simply select the image using kc finder and the finder generates the img tag which has errors.

Comment: Please provide necessary info: CKEditor version, KCFinder version, browser version. I tried CKEditor 4.0.2 with KCFinder 2.5.1 on latest Chrome and it works like a charm.

Comment: CKEditor 4.0.1 KCfinder v2.51 Problem persists on all browsers I tested (chrome , mozilla ...) I guess i miss configured something. Thats why i gave you code.

Comment: are using prepare statement when you try to store it in mysql?

Comment: Can you clarify if you were using CodeIgniter in this instance?

Comment: sorry for replying to your comment late , yes i was using CodeIgniter

Answer (score 0):

Things that could effect the output of your code :

1- [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) when using PDO. if they are ON, turn them OFF in you php.ini! they are deprecated. Why am I telling you this? will because in your source mode you had `300px; height: 224px;"`  when you stored it and displayed it you had `300px;="" height:="" 224px;"=""`

2- your CKeditor package. Try to download and reupload your Ckeditor (Update it to the last version if possible)

other than that, I do not see anything wrong with the code you have provided. Good luck!

Comment: THanks, but magic quites are not turned on. I still dont have any clue. I tried with a fresh package with no luck. I am moving on to tinyMCE.